# Graph algorithm to remove duplicate vertex and self loops from a adjacency list representation

Tags: algorithm, graph

Given an adjacency list representation of a directed multigraph is there a O(V+E) algorithm to convert it into undirected simple graph? The algorithm obiviously should use minimal space.

Comment: Depending on the language - but this is basically: `for each vertex v: v.edges = set(edges).remove(v)`

Answer (score 1):

**[EDIT 6/5/2013: Treat a[] consistently as a 2D array.]**

Yes, provided the vertices within each adjacency listed are in sorted order and there can be at most one edge in either between a pair of vertices.  Suppose the jth child of vertex i is a[i][j]:

```
# First make sure each edge appears only in the lower endpoint's adjacency list.
# We don't care if this duplicates vertices in a list.
For each vertex i:
    j = 1
    For each k from 1 to len(a[i]):
        a[i][j] = a[i][k]
        If a[i][k] > i:
            j = j + 1        # Only save space for edges to higher vertices

        If a[i][k] < i:
            Append i to a[a[i][k]]

    Adjust len(a[i]) to j - 1
```

At this point, every adjacency list consists of at most 2 sorted subsequences -- the original list of child vertices (with any higher vertices removed), possibly followed by a list of parent vertices appended from higher vertices' adjacency lists.  The start of the second sequence can be found in linear time by looking for the first element that is smaller than the previous element; if found, the two subsequences can be merged in linear time using a same-size buffer (or sorted in log-linear time using no extra space, or sorted in linear time using a bucket sort and logarithmic extra space).  No neighbour can appear more than twice, and any that are duplicated can be removed during the merge.